# SQL Impala - Grouping by inconsistent variable type and finding min, max, and difference

Tags: sql, impala

[image]

See attached picture above for how the data is formatted and what my goal is.

I am looking to make a query to group all pairs of the *CAB* variables together and create new columns for *High_BP* and *Low_BP* then find the difference of the these two *CABs FR*.

I can do this currently when there are just two *CAB* for every unique *ID* but some of the unique *ID* on some *DATE* and *Dest* will have anywhere from 2-4 different *CAB* configurations.

Anyone have any idea on where to start with this?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You did not mention your tablename so I just used Yourtable

```
select table1.Dest
    ,table1.Date
    ,table1.ID
    ,concat(table1.cab, table2.cab) as cab_pair
    ,case when table1.BP > table2.BP then table2.BP else table1.BP end as Low_BP
    ,case when table1.BP > table2.BP then table1.BP else table2.BP end as High_BP
    ,abs(table1.FR-table2.FR) as Diff_FR
from Yourtable as table1
inner join Yourtable as table2 
    on table1.id=table2.id and table1.cab > table2.cab
```

The only problem with the query is that the pairing will be done alphabetically with the first letter being farther in the alphabet, so instead of CF it will be FC.

Comment: i've updated my answer, I changed `table1.cab || table2.cab` into `concat(table1.cab, table2.cab) `

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it to work, I just added a group by for each variable and the case whens and it worked perfectly!